# Two overlapping rectangles

Tags: java, overlap

I'm having a lot of trouble figuring out what is wrong with my code. Actually, I'm having a very difficult time solving the problem of two rectangles overlapping. The following code should, theoretically, work for the following rectangles:

Rect1: (2.5, 4) width = 2.5, height = 43

Rect2: (1.5, 5) width = 0.5, height = 3

Keep in mind I can't use the Rectangle class to solve this problem. What I've done is calculated the x-values for the left and right edges and the y-values for the top and bottom edges of both rectangles.

I'm first considering -- and I know this does not cover all possible cases -- the scenario in which r2 is within r1.

Note that (x1, y1) and (x2, y2) signify the centers of rectangles 1 and 2, respectively.

```
right1 = x1 + w1/2;
left1 = x1 - w1/2;
bottom1 = y1 - h1/2;
top1 = y1 + h1/2;

right2 = x2 + w2/2;
left2 = x2 - w2/2;
bottom2 = y2 - h2/2;
top2 = y2 + h2/2;


overlap = (  (right2 < right1 && right2 > left1) &&
(bottom2 > bottom1 && bottom2 < top1) &&
(left2 > left1 && left2 < right1) &&
(top2 < top1 && top2 > bottom1) );
```

Again, I realize this scenario is not all-encompassing. But even at this point with testing if one rectangle is within another using the above Rect1 and Rect2 values for input, overlap evaluates to false...but it *shouldn't* -- I've done the math and suggests that the code should work. What did I do wrong?

Comment: "Keep in mind I can't use the Rectangle class to solve this problem" not for submission, but you can use it to compare your code to a known working implementation. This might help you to figure out the problem.

Comment: Your variable names are quite sporadic/confusing. Maybe if you went through them and picked better names, you'd spot any slight calculation problems.

Comment: @BrandonIbbotson What's so confusing about my variable names? Left/right/top/bottom signify the edges of the rectangles, and the calculations for these values are shown above in the code block. X1, Y1, X2, Y2 are the centers, W1, H1, W2, H2 are the widths and heights, respectively.

Comment: Do respect what @BrandonIbbotson has said. A rectangle is fully specified by two coordinates (x1, y1) and (x2, y2). That ought to be the notation you adopt and is the natural representation in a coordinate system that needs to know the location of the rectangles contained within it. Widths and heights are more to do with a coordinate system with respect to a *specific* rectangle. The "fully contained" case is then extremely simple to formulate. Coming from a general relativity background, I've learnt that an appropriate coordinate system is absolutely critical!

Comment: Ah I see, I thought that they were 2 dimensional co-ordinates for some reason. Still, `x1` and `w2` etc look a bit strange. You should ask yourself things like... **"Why is** `right1` **set to** `x1 + w1/2`? **Shouldn't it just be** `x1 + w1`?" With clearer variable names this process will be much more obvious.

Comment: No, because x1 is the center, and the width of the rectangle is not from the center to the right or to the left, it's the entire width. So to find the right edge, you have to divide width by 2. Edited the original post to clarify.

Comment: Yes, it was just an example of tracing through your code and asking yourself if it's correct.

Comment: So I'm really confused as to where I've gone wrong in my code. I've done the calculations by hand, and unless I've made a math mistake or a logic mistake in my code, it should work.

Comment: Einstein made many mistakes until Poincare reformulated all the mathematics. Your case is similar.

Comment: Okay, so I seem to have found a solution (I hope?). I was reading online, and it looks like testing for when the rectangles DON'T overlap is a much, much, much easier task than trying to cover all the bases of when they DO overlap.

Comment: Just split your overlap expressions and print the result of each. Then you can check what is wrong.

Comment: So I revised my code to dontOverlap = (  (bottom2 > top1) || (top2 < bottom1) || (right2 < left1) || (left2 > right1) );   -- it worked for the test scenario I was trying before.

Comment: Why can't you just google this? This has been answered a million times.

Comment: I did google it and did read the solutions provided by others on stack overflow. I did not understand why the chosen answers worked.

Comment: I think the problem in your code is you use strict comparisons `<` when the recatngles are sharing a part of an edge. Try `<=` and `>=` instead. However, I believe that BarrySW!)’s answer is correct and a better starting point than your own code (sorry).

Comment: And when I say `<=`, be further aware that float or double values are usually not exact. So it may still be that with a shared edge, Java will think they do not coincide. The solution is to allow for a minute difference. For instance, `x1 <= x4 + margin` where `margin` is a small constant, some 1-e10 or 1e-15 depending on which input you expect.

Comment: Thanks! But what's wrong with my code? Don't get me wrong, not being defensive, but to me it seems like a really simple solution -- just find when they don't overlap, negate it, and you know when they do overlap without getting into the nitty-gritty

Comment: Okay, just tried it out for a more complicated example, doesn't work. Urgh.

Comment: Excuse my idiocy, I was doing something wrong elsewhere in my code. But interesting thing learned from this regarding DeMorgan's Law -- negating the scenario when they don't collide will give you the code for when they do collide. Fascinating.

Answer (score 0):

Rectangles will be overlapping if there is some intersection between both their horizontal and vertical sides - so basically it's a case of checking whether two lines overlap for each dimension.

The check whether a line x1 -> x2 overlaps a line x3 -> x4 is whether the first line starts before the end of the second and ends after its start, or in code:

```
x1 <= x4 && x2 >= x3
```

To translate this to rectangles, apply the test to both dimensions:

```
(x1 <= x4 && x2 >= x3) && (y1 <= y4 && y2 >= y3)
```

..where one rectangle is x1,y1 -> x2,y2 and the other is x3,y3 -> x4,y4 (easily calculated from a start position and a width).